# Getting java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureOpenAndConnected in azure service bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-queues

We are getting the below exception continuously in azure service bus client, kindly help us to resolve this.

```
{
   "id":"1780511708",
   "outerId":"0",
   "type":"java.lang.RuntimeException",
   "message":"connectionId[MF_7487d6_1648134060148] IO Sink was interrupted before reactor closed.",
   "parsedStack":[
      {
         "level":0,
         "method":"com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorDispatcher.signalWorkQueue",
         "line":152,
         "fileName":"ReactorDispatcher.java"
      },
      {
         "level":1,
         "method":"com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorDispatcher.invoke",
         "line":105,
         "fileName":"ReactorDispatcher.java"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ClosedChannelException` tells you that the connection has been closed. It usually means either:

1. your application closed the connection somewhere else before you write the message or
2. your peer closed the connection before reading your message.

If you fix the above you should not see the ClosedChannelException anymore.